# Macosx and Helvetica license

Tags: mac, font-licensing

i was going to make a simple logo using Helvetica Neue font since i see it in my Mac fonts list (default fonts includes Helvetica Neue tho)

BUt i'm wondering, can i make an svg brand logo as well as use helvetica neue font on the brand website?

I will not host the font on server just wondering if buying the Mac the default fonts can be used for logo and branding :)

thanks any help appriciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since font was installed at your computer, you can use it.. if you use it to do a logo or any other ad, image, etc you can freely use your results of creative work. SVG will have just shapes instead of font letters, so you will not violate any license agreements. Cheers.

Comment: The Apple support confirmed what you said, thank you!